# What's the difference between a multiprocess.queue and multiprocess.pipe

Tags: python, queue, pipe, python-multiprocessing

I'm attempting to do some real-time (sort-of-ish) web-cam video processing. In order to both grab all the frames and process them, I'm running my frame grabber and image processor as two separate processes. In order to have them communicate I'm trying to decide between using python 2.7's `multiprocessing.queue` and `multiprocessing.pipe`.

I don't understand the difference between these two classes. One uses `put` and `get` to share data. The other uses `send` and `receive`. Is there a use-case where one would prefer on method over the other? Should I prefer one method over the other?

Comment: A pipe is a two-way street, a means of communication. A queue is just a pile of items to add to or take from.

Answer (score 0):

The `multiprocessing.queue` is First In First Out (FIFO) queue. You would use this for one-way communication. For example, your grabber process can `put()` frames onto the queue and the processing process can `get()` frames from the queue when it's ready to process them.

The `multiprocessing.pipe` is a 2-way channel and probably doesn't fit your use case. However, if you had 2 processes which were both sending and receiving data between each other you would use the two connection objects where process A `sends()` on one object and `recieves()` on the other object and process B does the inverse.